# How can I make tmux monitor a window for inactivity?

Tags: monitoring, tmux

I've switched from GNU Screen to [tmux](http://enwp.org/tmux).  They're both similar, except that tmux is still maintained.

GNU Screen has a `C-a _` ("silence") command. This command makes GNU Screen monitor the current window and alert me when there's been 30 seconds of inactivity. This is quite useful: for example, GNU Screen can watch a long `apt-get dist-upgrade` process and alert me when dpkg has a question for me.

Does tmux have an equivalent command? I tried [searching the Web](http://www.google.com/search?q=tmux+monitor+inactivity) but didn't find an answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The manpage reveals the answer.  You will need tmux 1.4 (released Dec. 2010) or better.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> then enter the command:

`:setw monitor-silence 30`

To identify all quiet windows in the session, apply the setting to all windows:

`:setw -g monitor-silence 30`

Comment: To stop monitoring for silence: `:setw monitor-silence 0`

Comment: While the effect is the usually same, the typical way to unset an option is `-u`, e.g. `:setw -u monitor-silence`. In this way it won't override any change in globally configured `monitor-silence`.